# I can not apply an overlay on top of an overlay using ffmpeg

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

As the title says, I can not apply an overlay on top of an overlay. More specifically, I have these layers:

1. background
2. video
3. stickers

And I want to create a fourth layer, on the size of 1 and 3rd layer. So the order I want to have is:

1. white layer
2. background
3. video
4. stickers

Following the documentation I came up with:

```
const command = [
           '-y', // always overwrite file
           '-loop', '1', // one time
           '-i', dataObject['bg_src'], // bg image
           '-i', dataObject['videos']['main']['src'], // video
           '-i', dataObject['fg_src'], // sticker image
           '-i', dataObject['fg_src'], // bg image2
           '-preset', 'veryfast', // fast encoding
           '-crf', '23', // quality
           '-vcodec','libx264', // codec
           '-t', '3', // time threshold
           '-loglevel', '24', // verbose level
           '-filter_complex',
           '[0:v]pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[bg_src];' +                      // bg_src: to make width even, export it as [bg_src]
           '[2:v]pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[fg_src];' +                      // fg_src: to make width even, export it as [fg_src]
           '[3:v]pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[fg_src2];' +                     // bg_src: to make width even, export it as [fg_src2]
           'color=white,format=rgb24[white_canvas];' +                          // create white background
           '[white_canvas][fg_src2]scale2ref[b][a];' +                          // make white background same size as [fg_src2]
           '[a][b]overlay=0:0[white_canvas_scaled];' +                          // export it as white_canvas_scaled
           '[1:v]scale=%s:-1[video_scaled];' +                                  // video: scale it (width is injected here)
           '[white_canvas_scaled][video_scaled]overlay=%s:%s:shortest=1[bg];' + // white background & scaled video
           '[bg][bg_src]overlay=0:0[bg2]',                                      // bg_src overlay here
           '[bg2][fg_src]overlay=0:0',                                          // fg_src overlay here
           FileService.photoPath + '/output.mp4'];
```

But in last command fails and I receive:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for '[bg2][fg_src]overlay=0:0'

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Missing semicolon ( and '+' ) near end of filter?